# Need to create a timer of 5 mins in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, timer, dispatcher

I'm a newbie to Silverlight.

Recently i downloaded a solution which records an Audio from the webpage present under silvoicerecordupload.codeplex.com/

What i'm trying to do is, The recording should stop after 5 mins.

I found some articles like:

[Dispatcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Timer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=VS.95).aspx)

I tried using the Dispatcher class, it just has Start() and Stop() methods,
but i cannot keep track of time that is being spent on the recording.

Please help me regarding this.

Thanks,
Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked the codeplex project but I'm assuming you have means of starting and stopping the recording via two methods. The timer will call the `StopRecording()` method as soon as the time specified by `recordingTimeInMilis` is used up.

```
public class TimedRecorder
{
    private const int recordingTimeInMilis = 5 * 60 * 1000;
    private Timer m_timer;
    public void StartRecording()
    {
        m_recorder.Start();
        m_timer = new Timer(
            StopRecording, null, recordingTimeInMilis, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
    public void StopRecording()
    {
        m_recorder.Stop();
        m_timer.Dispose();
        m_timer = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives the error as:The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Timer.Timer(System.Threading.TimerCallback, object, int, int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Yes, the callback needs to accept an object as input parameter. You can write it as a lambda, like so: `...new Timer( param => StopRecording, null, recordingTimeInMilis, Timeout.Infinite)...`